# Parquet file size doubles after deduplication in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, parquet

We have a deduplication process that reads parquet files and drops duplicate records and writes back the distinct dataframe in Spark sql as parquet output files.
But the output file size doubles it's original size. We are writing the parquet with gzip compression that is also the original file compression codec.

Comment: Can you count how many partitions you have? I suspect it is very high and that you need to repartition the dataframe before writing it. Can you also confirm the row counts of before and after to ensure the process is working?

Comment: The number of files are less after dedup process also the count is less than actual dataframe.